# Google Maps shows blank map using google_maps_flutter plugin

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm working on an app that uses the [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin (version 0.5.7) to display a map. It was working just perfectly until yesterday. I didn't do any updates to my app, it just stopped displaying a blank map when I opened it today. Flutter Doctor doesn't show any problem, and the same with Flutter Analyze. The plugin seems to be partially working, because I'm using the `GoogleMap` `onTap` property to show the coordinates of the location tapped, and it works just fine (`I/flutter (11935): LatLng(25.895589930847475, -80.28307791799307)`, although the marker is not created.

```
_handleTap(LatLng point) {
  setState(() {
     print(point);
    _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(point.toString()),
        position: point,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: point.toString(),
        ),
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
   ));
  });
}
```

Any ideas, what could be happening? Has any issue been reported for this plugin that could cause this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Please use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: I'm just guessing I haven't tried google map on flutter. Probably it is something to do with the map key api.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. On iOS its a white screen, and Android grey.  I've double checked my api key, so pretty sure that's not it. I've also noticed in Google's api console, it does acknowledge an iOS request, but doesn't show anything for Android.

Comment: @eimmer did you find the answer?

Comment: @Anton I did, but sadly I'm not sure what the specific issue was. I decided to restart a tutorial from scratch, and it worked without issue.  Wish I could offer more help.

Comment: @Anton I fixed my issue too, but just like eimmer, I'm not really sure what worked of the many things I did, including updating the plug-in, restarting from scratch the whole thing. I saved a copy of the non working version somewhere, I'll try to compare to see what I did.

Comment: @cubanGuy huge thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Log in to the [Google Cloud Platform Console][1].
2. Click the
   project drop-down and select or create the project for which you
   want to add an API key.
3. Click the menu (top-left hamburger)
   button  and select APIs & Services > Credentials.
4. On the Credentials page, click Create credentials > API key. Repeat this
   step to create 2 keys.
5. In your Flutter project, ensure the
   following files use an active API key:

   - android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
   - ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift
6. Click the menu (top-left hamburger) button  and select APIs & Services > Library
7. Click on
   each of the following items and then click 'Enable'

   - Maps SDK for Android
   - Maps SDK for iOS
8. I would suggest going back to the API keys you created in step 3 and then restricting one to iOS apps and the Maps
   SDK for iOS and the other to Android and the Maps SDK for Android.

   [1]: https://cloud.google.com/console/google/maps-apis/overview

Answer (score 3):

***It might be because of Connectivity problem in Emulator(wifi/internet)***

**Change the DNS address of your network to 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS) or another of your preference:**

MacOSX:

Open "System Preferences"
Click on "Network"
Select the network which your computer is connected
click on "Advanced"
Select "DNS", Select the "+" button, type "8.8.8.8" (Google's DNS) or if you prefer OpenDNS, "208.67.222.222"
Select "Ok" and "Apply"

Windows & Linux:
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

After that close the emulator and start it again.

Comment: My country is blocked. I ran a `VPN` app on my phone, closed the app, ran it again, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I did have a similar problem in iOS. Make sure you enable both apis in google developers console. maps for iOS and maps for Android. Key can be shared or generate for each platform.